# clone a variable in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a dictionary of arrays as follow:

```
var usersTemp = {11: [ {"active": true, "email": "seconduser@example.com", "userid": 2, } ],
            12:  [ {"active": true, "email": "firstuser@example.com", "userid": 1, },
                   {"active": true, "email": "seconduser@example.com", "userid": 2, } ], }
```

I need to merge the elements that have the same email address or userid and get something similar to this:

```
{ 1: {"active": true, "email": "firstuser@example.com", "roles": [12]} ,
  2: {"active": true, "email": "seconduser@example.com", "roles": [11 , 12]}, }
```

This is my try:

```
var mergedUsersTemp = {};
for (var role in usersTemp) {
    for (var user in usersTemp[role]) {
        if(!mergedUsersTemp[user]){
            const i = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(usersTemp[role][user]));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(i))
            mergedUsersTemp[user] = {"active": i["active"], "email": i["email"], "id": i["id"], "roles": []};
            mergedUsersTemp[user]["roles"] = [];
        }
        mergedUsersTemp[user]["roles"].push(role);
    }
}
```

But the problem is deep copy in javascript and it's returning the same value for the user info. How can I fix it?

Comment: whats your current output?

Comment: @Jonasw I've replicated OP's current code [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/pnd69dro/).

Comment: `user` is the index in the array, not the user ID. Try `var uid = usersTemp[role][user]['userid'];` and use that in `if(!mergedUsersTemp[uid])` and so on. This seems to give the result you want.

Comment: Don't use `for...in...` for an array: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). Not a problem here, but don't let it become a habit :)

Comment: And what's with all the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` lately? O.o

Comment: If in result 1 and 2 are userid's then why 1 has 11 and 12, shouldn't it be the other way.

Comment: @NenadVracar Based on the email addresses this was a typo on the ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for...in` loop its easier to use `Object.keys()` and `forEach` loop. Then you just need to first check if `userid` already exists in object and set its value or add to roles and change active.

```js
var usersTemp = {
  11: [{
    "active": true,
    "email": "seconduser@example.com",
    "userid": 2,
  }],
  12: [{
    "active": true,
    "email": "firstuser@example.com",
    "userid": 1,
  }, {
    "active": true,
    "email": "seconduser@example.com",
    "userid": 2,
  }],
}

var result = {}
Object.keys(usersTemp).forEach(function(i) {
  usersTemp[i].forEach(function(j) {
    if (!result[j.userid]) {
      result[j.userid] = {
        active: j.active,
        email: j.email,
        roles: []
      }
    }
    result[j.userid].roles.push(i)
    result[j.userid].active = j.active
  })
})

console.log(result)
```